# How do I get initial transition matrix probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, algorithms, anomaly-detection

I have to develop a system to detect and prevent bank transactions fraud - just credit card transactions, for simplicity - I'm thinking about using markov chain.

How would I get the initial transitions matrix probabilities? Do I have to use past transactions data?

And what exactly can I do with Markov chain? Can I actually predict ahead of time a possible fraud? Or just use it to detect outliers and identify actual frauds?

PS: Any advice, books or resources on developing such a system would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a school project?

Comment: @EngrStudent yes, it's for school not meant for actual production

Comment: I might check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151327/need-a-data-set-for-fraud-detection) question.  It has some initial data.

Comment: @EngrStudent i don't see how that question helps me... I don't need dataset, my question is a theory question about markov chain

Comment: You might want to put the tag "homework" in the question.  I was thinking that the names of public data might lead you to previous papers, approaches, and results that you can benchmark your personal results against.

Comment: @EngrStudent homework? Do you know how to get markov chain transition matrices probabilities or not?

Comment: Here is a worksheet on the making the transition probability matrices that starts simple, and works its way up. [link](http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/upload/classbfs1210015600141823.pdf)

Comment: @EngrStudent thanks that kind of help, but on that link they assume things like "Dt+1 has a poisson distribution". In my case I can't make those assumptions I only have previous data. Should I use this a data as training data to find my transition matrix? Is this how we do it?

Comment: It is one way.  The job of every teacher is to put themselves out of a job.  They do that by giving you the fundamentals and teaching you how to teach yourself. That is also how to train very capable people. ...  The transition matrix, in physical systems is a "state transition matrix", so several disciplines use this and there are many ways.  If you were looking for simplest approach, and you knew your data was all continuous and your "system" was linear, you could use a matrix pseudo-inverse.  There are probably a dozen ways to do this that are built around different assumptions and needs.